# How do you find a plane formed by two vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, orthonormal

I believe that if you take the normal of those two vectors, it gives you the coefficients of that sought plane, but I don't understand why that is so. So you have two vectors on the same plane, the normal should give you a vector that's perpendicular to both. Using the hand notation to find the orientation of the vector, I don't understand how a vector perpendicular to those two vectors will give me the needed coefficients. When I visualize the plane formed by that vector, it's on the wrong plane altogether.

My question in regards to you can use normals to find planes came up in the following question:

Given two curves on a surface and a point, (2,1,3), find a plane tangent to that point. After finding the tangent vector corresponding to those curves and point, I believe you're supposed to use the normal to find the tangent plane, and I'm fine with the computations, but I don't understand why the normal of the two tangent vectors will give you the coefficients of the tangent plane.

Comment: Vectors don't have a position, so you can't uniquely define a plane by two vectors.  You need at least one point on the plane.

Comment: Sorry. I have a point on a surface (2,1,3), and two tangent curves, from which I derived two tangent vectors at the given point, V1: 3i - 4k and V2: 2i + 6k + 2k. I'm trying to derive a tangent plane from this information. I think I find the normal vector then plug it into the tangent EQ formula, but I don't understand why the normal vector will give me the needed scalar/coefficients.

Comment: Do edit your clarifications into your Question, and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813). It's currently possible to answer your Question from multiple angles, but I feel that your queries (pertaining to this Question) will focus or even clear up when you try to formulate your Question more thoughtfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the normal vector will give you the coefficients of the equation of the tangent plane is as follows:

Let the normal vector be $$\underline{n}=\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right)$$

Suppose the point $A$ with position vector $\underline{a}$ is a known fixed point on the plane and the position vector of a general point on the plane is given by
$$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then for every such point on the plane, we must have $$(\underline{r}-\underline{a})\perp\underline{n}$$

Hence
$$(\underline{r}-\underline{a})\cdot\underline{n}=0$$
$$\implies \underline{r}\cdot\underline{n}=\underline{a}\cdot\underline{n}$$
which is a constant $d$, say.

Hence in Cartesian form the equation of the plane is $$ax+by+cz=d$$

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the normal vector to the plane is found by the cross-product of the two given vectors.

With the normal vector,$ N=<a,b,c>$ in hand, the equation of the plane is  $$ a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)= 0 $$   where $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is any point on the plane.

Comment: Yes, my question is not how to get the plane, but why it is that the normal vector of the two tangent vectors will give you the coefficients for the tangent plane. I don't see the relation between a plane perpendicular to two tangent vectors to the surface and the tangent plane to the point itself. The way that I envision it, the plane would be formed by the two vectors and the normal would be any line which forms a 90$^{\circ}$ with the tangent plane at the point, rather than the tangent plane itself.